# How exactly can someone without source code access exploit a non-final class that has a constructor which invokes overridable functions?

Tags: java, security, static-analysis, fortify

I'm trying to understand how exactly can someone that doesn't already have access to the source code exploit a non-final class that has a constructor which invokes overridable functions (functions not marked final).

This question comes from the fact that after scanning my source code with a Source Code Analyzer (Fortify), it showed a few findings about "Code Correctness: Constructor Invokes Overridable Function".

Some of the references for the issue, or bad practice, are:

1. Guideline 4-5 / EXTEND-5: Limit the extensibility of classes and methods ([link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#4))
2. Guideline 7-4 / OBJECT-4: Prevent constructors from calling methods that can be overridden ([link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#7))

I understand why the code is being flagged and I also understand how I can mitigate/remove the finding. But I'd like to understand how someone could actually exploit this unless they have access to the source code. Since in that case, they could really just wreak havoc and wouldn't care much about this triviality. Surely I am missing something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need source code to extend a class and overwrite some methods - you only need the corresponding `.class` file for that.

Suppose you would do something dumb like

```
public class PayFlowjoe {
  public PayFlowjoe() {
    sendMoneyTo(getRecipient());
  }

  protected String getRecipient() {
    return "flowjoe";
  }

  private void sendMoneyTo(String recipient) {
    System.out.println("Sending money to " + recipient);
  }
}
```

then I could create a class

```
public class PayMe extends PayFlowjoe {
  protected String getRecipient() {
    return "me";
  }
}
```

and creating an instance of `PayMe` would send money to me instead of you. To compile `PayMe`, you only need the `PayFlowjoe.class` file. To create an instance of `PayMe` and trigger the bad code, you simply need to put `PayFlowjoe.class` in the classpath of the application that uses `PayMe`.

By the way - it is actually fairly easy to use a decompiler to get the `PayFlowjoe` source code from the `PayFlowjoe.class` file.

Comment: Ok. A follow-up question if I may... Say my app is built as a WAR. An attacker that can somehow get a hold of the WAR can make the changes you mentioned. Could it also be possible for them to somehow insert the bad code (in the above scenario, the PayMe class) and figure out a way to run it from my app?

Comment: "Possible" as in the most theoretical and general sense? Yes, it is possible. In practice? It depends. Since WAR usually means a server application, the attacker would need to get access to your server to replace the WAR on the server. Of course, there are a lot of news about security breaches, but "breaking in" is a whole lot more difficult than my silly example above.

Comment: Actually, the recent log4shell vulnerability would have enabled an attacker to insert any kind of malicious code into "your" application - including something like the `PayMe` class - **without** having to replace your WAR.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to assume that an attacker did get a hold of the WAR and was able to modify the contents. So, that also sort of answered my follow up question. Thanks!!